# Is cookie still used?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

While I was reading about cookies, I tried the following in browser console:-
document.cookie = "username=John Doe";

result:-
SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure.

Comment: yes, you can use cookies unless you disabled it

Comment: Why my browser console is giving this error!

Comment: Your extension or bundle disabled cookies.

Comment: @RohitBhardwag what broswer you are using

Comment: @RohitBhardwag could you try this in your console? document.cookie

Comment: You might need a secure website (https) that would probably allow it to work. You can enable it during development in browser, but will need to be secure when live

Comment: I am using safari

Answer (score 2):

Yes cookies are still used and are extremely important. One of the most used form of cookies is your **Session** key.

**Let's understand a bit of the fundamentals:**

A cookie is just a piece of information that is stored on your computer for some purpose. Each website you go on can store information, and access the stored information, **BUT** they can only access the cookies their domain stored (for security reasons).

So yes, they are STILL ESSENTIAL for almost all the websites you go to. Facebook, Google, you name it.

Comment: @slebetman you caught me, subliminal messaging to make the world a happier place

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are. Some browsers disable the cookies for some websites, but you can enable them.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is more important to store session key in browser/ some mobile application for future access to the server.